Selecting text inside TextField actions not translated iOS
I have a TextField inside my app. When long pressing a text inside the TextField, it gives the user the ability to do 5 actions : "cut", "copy", "look up", "search web" and "share".
However, even thought the phone is in french, the app also is in french, only the first two actions ("cut"->"couper" and "copy"->"Copier")  are translated to french, the last three are in english :


How to also translate the last three action to french ? "look up", "search web" and "share" ?
I am testing that on simulator iPhone 15 pro max, settings language french, iOS 17.2. Same issue on real devices.

Inside the flutter/dart code, nothing seems relevant expect the TextInputAction.search :
TextField(
  cursorColor: context.themeColors.xxx,
  onTap: onTextFieldTap,
  focusNode: _node,
  controller: _controller,
  onSubmitted: (_) {
    xxx
  },
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.search,
  onChanged: (String value) {
    xxx
  },
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp(xxx),
    ),
  ],
  style: context.texts.paragraph.copyWith(
    color: xxx,
  ),
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    xxx
  ),
),

Thank you for you help !
=>
I am on flutter version 3.16.8, that's why. I should upgrade to at least 3.19.0
3.16.8 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3.16.8/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/cupertino_fr.arb
3.19.0 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3.19.0/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/cupertino_fr.arb
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

=> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3.16.8/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/cupertino_fr.arb

Legic Flutter issue. They forgot to translate some keys.


Thank you, indeed I should uprage flutter from 3.16.8 to at least 3.19.0
3.16.8 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3.16.8/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/cupertino_fr.arb
3.19.0 => https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/3.19.0/packages/flutter_localizations/lib/src/l10n/cupertino_fr.arb
